# LINQ-to-SQL - The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type 

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have an issue with a LINQ query I am working on. This has worked perfect for a while, but we did a rollback of the database and now it doesn't work.

Basically, I'm inserting a new row into a table which has an autogenerating BigInt PK. But when SubmitChanges is called I get this error:

> The null value cannot be assigned to a
>   member with type System.Int64 which is
>   a non-nullable value type

I've looked at the generated SQL, and the issue seems to likely revolve arond this after the insert:

> SELECT CONVERT(BigInt,
>   SCOPE_IDENTITY()) AS [value]

This seems to be returning null, but I have no idea why. Both the table and the LINQ dmbl are set up correctly for autogenerating PK's.

Any ideas?

EDIT: After some debugging, including trying an insert manually in SQL as someone kindly suggested, I've stumbled upon a very strange issue -

'Column or expression 'Outstanding' cannot be updated'

Outstanding is a non-nullable decimal(9,2) field

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on you SubmitChanges call, does the record get inserted into the DB with the correct Auto Incrementing ID value ?

Comment: ok, if you Open Up your DBML file, right click on the Property in question (ie: the ID column thats generating a 0, and click "Peroperties.. .then check if the Property "Auto Generated Value" is set to True ?

Comment: Yup, it's set to true- that's the first thing I tried.

Comment: Please include your table schema as well as your insert sql

Comment: Is outstanding a calculated column?

Comment: Normally, this occurrs when the column is a calculated column, or a guid or something... can you add your Table Schema to the post so we can verify ?

Comment: You may want to consider asking a new question regarding the new issue, per [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93513/initial-issue-is-resolved-leading-to-second-issue-update-question-or-new-quest/93516#93516)

Comment: If you could perhaps post the DDL for the table and the text of the INSERT statement perhaps someone could see what's going on.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/726c8c17-d5cc-4696-ae90-406118311c73#3064f233-e6f3-4d23-845f-0ec3eaed60f2) - someone else had the same error as you, same situation. It turns out that there was an issue with running the actual insert, which resulted in no record being inserted. Then when `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` was called, it returned null, since no record was inserted.

Try running a straight `Insert` of the same values into the table through your Sql Management tool, and see if the row inserts properly. There might be some other issue that is preventing this (aside from the autogenerating PKs), which would be the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've added some more information to my post as I've encountered some more errors